# How to make a panoramic view?

Tags: software-recommendations, panorama

I would like to create panoramic images such as the ones in the attatchment. My current software pallate is ESRI Advanced, SAFE FME,Adobe Illustrator and of course anything opensource.

[image]

I could fumble around with Illustrator to make similar results, but I thought someone might have made something similar.

Comment: Do you want the panoramic image viewable in desktop software or do you want it available on the web?

Comment: If web you could use photosphere https://www.google.com/maps/about/contribute/photosphere/

Comment: I think the final image is going to be used to engrave a metal plate...so firstly desktop use is a priority.

Comment: Needs to be mirrored vectors for engraving so use illustrator http://www.ponoko.com/starter-kits/adobe-illustrator#illustrator_section_1

Comment: Starting from what data? For an engraving, colour is no use, right?

Comment: I was hoping for some guidance regarding workflows to recreate the outlines of the mountain relief from either a DEM of a panorama photo. Anyone done this before? I´m not interested in getting a photo- rather the digital lines to create the form from a certain coordinate in a specific direction.

Answer (score 1):

I just helped out our building manager for doing something similar. She wanted 11x17's of the view out the top floor of our new building with an image of the buildings in the view out to the horizon and the schools that were in the view (though not visible).

I ended up using an [old version of SketchUp](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-sketchup/) and the [ENJSHAPE plugin for SketchUp](https://github.com/enjalot/enjshape/tree/master) (SketchUp version 7.0.1247 worked for me) which allows .SHP's to be imported into SketchUp. *Unfortunately the ENJSHAPE plugin is no longer in development, but this particular workaround still works...*

With ENJSHAPE enabled I could load in [OSM Polygons](https://mapzen.com/metro-extracts), approximate their height using the SketchUp 'extrude' function.

I then took our School Points GIS file, and added an extruded circle (blue pole looking thing below) and an annotation callout for the schools that were in the view.

The result looked like this:

[image]

From there, I took a screen capture of the view from SketchUp, pasted it into an Inkscape Layout, and through the borders, logo on there.

This ended up being too 'blocky' looking, so she took photos herself, and used the school callouts as her guide to annotating her own photos, and the result basically looked like my image above with a real photo in the background... we were both happy with the result!

Comment: Interesting..thanks for the reply. I also came upon a post which uses a 3d maperative export loaded into Google Sketch up. Problem is now finding 3D Data for Norway.